# DotNetNuke Service API Authorization throwing 401 Unauthorized code

Tags: service, authorization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out why I am getting `401 Unauthorized` status from service framework. At the moment I have it setup to allow everyone to do as they please but that because when I try to enable authorisation I get 401 error code.

```
//[SupportedModules("Boards")]
//[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class BoardsServiceController : DnnApiController
{ ... }
```

The strange thing is I have another module which is more than happy to work away with DnnModuleAuthorize

```
[SupportedModules("Assignments")]
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View)]
public class AsgnsServiceController : DnnApiController
{ ... }
```

In both cases I have checked to make sure the user has permissions to view the page on which the module lives.

I have cross referenced both projects and everything seems to be spot on. Yet one is working away just fine and the other one returns 401.

Any suggestions?

#### Update

For Assignments module I am mostly using `jQuery` style of ajax request just because I haven't got around to revising the module. So a typical `GET` request would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: sf.getServiceRoot( "Assignments" ) + "AsgnsService/GetAssignments",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders
}).done( function ( items ) {
    //removed for brevity
}).fail( function ( xhr, result, status ) {
    //removed for brevity
});
```

As for Boards module the code structure is slightly different due knockout implementation. There is a dedicated `ServiceCaller` but it all boils down to the same ajax call to the server except that instead of having full blown ajax call defined as above it looks much neater.

```
var that = this;

that.serviceCaller = new dnn.boards.ServiceCaller($, this.moduleId, 'BoardsService');

var success = function (model) {
    if (typeof model !== "undefined" && model != null) {
        viewModel = new boardViewModel(model.colLists);

        ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.beforeMove = viewModel.verifyAssignments;
        ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = viewModel.updateLastAction;

        // normally, we apply moduleScope as a second parameter
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, settings.moduleScope);
    }

    //console.log('success', model);
};

var failure = function (response, status) {
    console.log('request failure: ' + status);
};

var params = {
    BoardId: this.boardId
};

that.serviceCaller.get('GetBoardLists', params, success, failure);
```

And the `ServiceCaller` ajax function itself looks like this:

```
function (httpMethod, method, params, success, failure, synchronous) {
    var options = {
        url: that.getRoot() + method,
        beforeSend: that.services.setModuleHeaders,
        type: httpMethod,
        async: synchronous == false,
        success: function (d) {
            if (typeof (success) != 'undefined') {
                success(d || {});
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof (failure) != 'undefined') {
                var message = undefined;

                if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('application/json') == 0) {
                    try {
                        message = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).Message;
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                }

                failure(xhr, message || errorThrown);
            }
        }
    };

    if (httpMethod == 'GET') {
        options.data = params;
    } else {
        options.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
        options.data = ko.toJSON(params);
        options.dataType = 'json';
    }

    $.ajax(options);
};
```

This would be the two GET requests from two different modules where one is happy and the other throws a status 401 when I enable the same annotations.

Does this provide any clues?

#### Update

Now in saying all of the above if one takes a look at the original [Boards module code base](https://dnnboards.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DNNCorp/Boards/Components/Services/BoardsServiceController.cs) one will notice `[DnnAuthorize]` annotation attached to every function.

During module revision I removed all instances of `[DnnAuthorize]` annotation and replaced it with two of my own on the service class itself.

When I add `[DnnAuthorize]` as annotation on service class itself things work as expected. So why `[SupportedModules("Boards")]` and `[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View)]` combination doesn't !?

Comment: Can you show your code that is calling the service?

Comment: I hope my latest update help to shed some light on what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but working with the WebAPI you have to register the Service Framework anti forgery stuff

```
 ServicesFramework.Instance.RequestAjaxAntiForgerySupport();
```

This is part of asking the API to work with a specific module.

Comment: I have this registered inside ``OnInit()`` along with some other scripts. But I thought its only used with ``[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`` annotation to double check validity of the requests. Particularly POST requests.

Comment: could be - mine is a lot simpler so maybe the complexity is hiding something are you loading a var with the jquery servcie framework -  var sf = $.ServicesFramework(moduleid);

Comment: Yep, its defined inside ``ServiceCaller`` as ``this.services = $.dnnSF(moduleId);``

Comment: Actually, do you know if ``<packageName>`` or ``<moduleName>`` from manifest file is used to match against ``[SupportedModules("?")]`` annotation? Or is it something else entirely?